# Count rows in an Ajax sourced datatable(including paginated rows) with specific column value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have an Ajax sourced Datatable, I want to count rows in `#datatableOne` where column 'Status' has a value 'Unknown'. I've tried the following.

This only counts the rows in the active page

```
function tableOneRowCount(){
    var rows = $("#datatableOne td:nth-child():contains('Unknown')" ).length;
    alert("Unknown rows :" + rows);
}
```

And this also not includes the paginated rows unless you make them visible once. so unless I select 2nd page it won't include 'Unknown' rows for 2nd page.

```
function tableOneRowCount(){
    var table = $('#datatableOne').DataTable();
    var rows = table.rows(':contains("Unknown")').data().length;
    alert("unknown rows : " + rows);
}
```

Need help in this as I don't have a very solid experience in javascript.

Following is the way how I'm loading my datatable.

```
var tableOne = $('#datatableOne').DataTable({
        ajax:{
            url: '@Url.Action("AssetsUnderContract_AjaxHandler", "SiteReport")',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { "SiteReportID": SiteReportID }
        },
        "bProcessing": true,
        "columns": [
            {"data": "report_asset_id"},
            {"data": "product_name"},
            {"data": "serial_number"},
            {"data": "description"},
            {"data": "site_location"},
            {"data": "asset_guarantee"},
            {"data": "asset_calibration_status"}
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
            "targets": 7,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": '<button class="btn btn-round btn-primary btn-xs" type="button">Load</button>'
            }
        ],
        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {       

            if(aData["asset_guarantee"] == true){
                $("td:eq(5)", nRow).text("").wrapInner('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>').css("text-align", "center")
            }else {
                $("td:eq(5)", nRow).text("").wrapInner('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>').css("text-align", "center")
            }

            if(aData["asset_calibration_status"] == 0){
                $("td:eq(6)", nRow).text("Unknown").wrapInner('<span class="label label-default"></span>').css("text-align", "center")
            }else if(aData["asset_calibration_status"] == 1){
                $("td:eq(6)", nRow).text("Completed").wrapInner('<span class="label label-success"></span>').css("text-align", "center")
            }else if(aData["asset_calibration_status"] == 2){
                $("td:eq(6)", nRow).text("Not Found").wrapInner('<span class="label label-danger"></span>').css("text-align", "center")
            }else if(aData["asset_calibration_status"] == 3){
                $("td:eq(6)", nRow).text("Pending").wrapInner('<span class="label label-danger"></span>').css("text-align", "center")
            }
            return nRow;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `data()` method to retrieve all of the rows from `tableOne` like so after you load the data:

```
tableOne.data().length
```

This will give you a count of all of your rows in JavaScript.  To filter just on `status === 'unknown'`, you could do an `each()` on your `data()` to count them.

```
var unknownCount = 0;
tableOne.data().each(function(row) {
    if (row.status === 'unknown') {
        unknownCount = unknownCount + 1;
    }
}
```

I'm assuming `row` is an object, but it might not be, but hopefully this gets you on the right track.